# Filter Start Menu Search Result in windows

Tags: windows

I am looking for a solution in which I want to filter the windows start menu search result. I want to hide some programs that are installed in PC. But I still want a search text box in start menu. for example i want to hide bluestack from result. and even if the user search bluestack from start menu then the search result should not display bluestack in the result. i have hide all the recent and installed programs from start menu but the drawback is if user search that program he can find it. Is there any kind of software or another solution to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a trick myself to do that. We can do this by right click on that program folder in the start menu like bluestack and go to properties and then check hidden from check box and then apply changes. That's all we need. Now even if I search it on start menu the bluestack will not display in the search result. –